# Keys getting stuck in virtualbox 5.0

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, keyboard, virtual-machine

Sometimes when I hold a key down or scroll too quickly with with my mousewheel, my virtual box VM will lock the key as pressed. The VM will then stop responding to any further input until (usually) I minimize and maximize the VM window.

This is pretty annoying as I do a lot of text editing and having your delete or backspace key stuck is never a good thing.

I'm running a windows 7 guest VM on red hat 6.7 host with virtual box 5.0   (I had the problem with older versions as well)

Anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: 1.  Welcome!  2.  This may be a bug.  If it is, you should report it in the VirtualBox bug tracker so that (hopefully) they can fix it in time for the next version of VirtualBox.